\tdplotdrawpolytopearc -- dimensions too large
I am obtaining a dimensions too large error when trying to use \tdplotdrawpolytopearc.
See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/733935/319072.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotdefinepoints(-1,2,2)(2,2,1)(1,-1,2)
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[ultra thick, green]{1}{}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


*This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.3.29)  31 DEC 2024 13:08
 system commands enabled.
**name.tex
(./name.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-resolved path "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count186
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count187
\c@sapage=\count188
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for 'standalone' class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count189
\c@section=\count190
\c@subsection=\count191
\c@subsubsection=\count192
\c@paragraph=\count193
\c@subparagraph=\count194
\c@figure=\count195
\c@table=\count196
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/luatex85/luatex85.sty
Package: luatex85 2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks20
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen140
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen141
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks21
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks22
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks23
))
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@xb=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@xc=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\pgf@xd=\dimen152
\pgf@yd=\dimen153
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count197
\c@pgf@countb=\count198
\c@pgf@countc=\count199
\c@pgf@countd=\count266
\t@pgf@toka=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks26
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count267
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count268
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count269
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 274.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen154
\pgfmath@count=\count270
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks27
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks28
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks29
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count271
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen155
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen156
\pgf@picminy=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen158
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen159
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@xx=\dimen163
\pgf@xy=\dimen164
\pgf@yx=\dimen165
\pgf@yy=\dimen166
\pgf@zx=\dimen167
\pgf@zy=\dimen168
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen169
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen170
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen171
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen172
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count272
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen173
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen174
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen176
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen177
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen178
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count273
\pgf@shadingcount=\count274
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen179
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen180
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen181
\pgffor@skip=\dimen182
\pgffor@stack=\toks30
\pgffor@toks=\toks31
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count275
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen183
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen184
\tikz@lasty=\dimen185
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen186
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen189
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen190
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen191
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count276
\tikznumberofchildren=\count277
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count278
\tikz@fig@count=\count279
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count280
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count281
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count282
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count283
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
\sa@box=\box62
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary3d.code.tex
File: tikzlibrary3d.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\arrowsize=\dimen192
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count284
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = output.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count285
\scratchdimen=\dimen193
\scratchbox=\box64
\nofMPsegments=\count286
\nofMParguments=\count287
\everyMPshowfont=\toks32
\MPscratchCnt=\count288
\MPscratchDim=\dimen194
\MPnumerator=\count289
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count290
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks33
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))
angles for cross product: phi: 213.68979theta: 158.16777
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x 
           
l.8 ...rawpolytopearc[ultra thick, green]{1}{left}{}
                                                  
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

[1

Missing character: There is no - (U+002D) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no - (U+002D) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no + (U+002B) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no + (U+002B) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ( (U+0028) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no - (U+002D) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 3 (U+0033) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . (U+002E) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , (U+002C) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no - (U+002D) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 (U+0032) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . (U+002E) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , (U+002C) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no - (U+002D) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 9 (U+0039) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . (U+002E) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 (U+0030) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) (U+0029) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont!
] (./output.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 14000 strings out of 476435
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 413 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 5 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:480,3:90,4:28,5:22,6:2,7:731,9:66,11:9
 35704 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 15 fonts using 723367 bytes
 117i,7n,114p,412b,763s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 1144 bytes).

PDF statistics: 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 16 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)*

